# Is there an automatic way to resize images to a specific dimension. (blur background and not crop image)

Tags: images, resize, background, blur, multiple-sizes

Lets say that I choose a bunch of differents images with diferentes dimensions and sizes (for example)

[image]

And then I want all files with 1600 X 900px, and magically it transform all images in something like that:

[image]

*(it blurs the same image in the background witch is occupying 100% of the size that i choose before, and position the image on the center without crop the original image)*

So basically I want an automatic way to do it. It can be anything, a specific program, a website, a configuration on illustrator... seriously, anything.

Comment: This can be accomplished on Photoshop, search for it

Comment: @Luciano there is a way to automatically do this?! I've always had to do it manually.  Do you know the name of the action or script?

Comment: Just a note, in conversation I've found many people including myself find this effect extremely irritating.

Comment: there is a way to do it automatically, but you have to create the action / script yourself. @DigitalLightcraft I also find it annoying, either in video or photos; I'd rather crop the image differently.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I agree, but there are often times when there is no other option.  I mentioned this issue here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/89787/how-to-fit-a-vertical-headshot-into-a-horizontal-frame

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with others who have commented that such edits are often annoying, but anyway, that's not what you asked. You asked if it was possible to automate it, and it certainly is possible.

You could do it in Photoshop by recording an action to automate it.

Begin recording a new action, with the image already open:

1. Click Image > Image size, and resize it to 900px high with maintain aspect ratio checked, and resample checked
2. Select all (CTRL+A), and copy (CTRL+C)
3. Click File > New, select the clipboard size.
4. Hit paste (CTRL+V)
5. Image > Image size, and resize to 1600px wide with maintain aspect ratio checked, resample checked
6. Apply a gaussian or lens blur
7. Select all (CTRL+A), copy (CTRL+C). Close the document, don't save
8. Set canvas size to 1600 wide, 900 high.
9. Paste (CTRL+V) the blurred layer
10. Select all (CTRL+A), hit the Align Vertical Centres icon in the toolbar along the top
11. Click and drag the blurred layer under the unblurred layer in the layers panel.

Stop recording the action.

Then you could open any image, and play back the action. You could even play the action back using the File > Automate > Batch, on a whole folder full of images.

Here's an example of what the action does. You can see the action steps in the actions palette.

[image: Example created with the action]